# Installing c++ packages during Docker build

Tags: c++, docker

I have a dockerfile for running a c++ application. Part of the docker file has the following command :

```
RUN tar -xvf boost_1_56_0.tar.bz2 && \
cd boost_1_56_0 && \
./bootstrap.sh && \
./b2 install
```

The tar file is part of docker image.
The problem is that each time I build the dockerfile the entire package gets installed which takes an awful amount of time. How can I prevent it ?

Comment: Can't you use a base image that allows you to install boost from packages?

Comment: @whites11 the base image is centos:7 there will be version issues in yum repository right ?

Comment: I don't know, but you can find a base images that has a packages system that provides boost 1.56 I guess

Answer (score 1):

If nothing has changed up to and including a command in a docker file, then Docker will used the cached data from a previous build. So if you have something like this:

```
ADD ./myfiles /path/in/container  # changes each time
RUN tar -xvf boost # etc
```

Then boost will be rebuilt every time. But if reorganise your Dockerfile like this:

```
RUN tar -xvf boost # etc
ADD ./myfiles /path/in/container  # changes each time
```

Then the binary build of boost from your last docker build will be reused from the cache. More generally, put things earlier in the Docker file the less likely they are to change.

Comment: So with respect to the commands that I have, what should be the fix ?

Comment: @MukulChakravarty You would need to post significantly more of your Dockerfile for me to say precisely what to change. But you could make the changes yourself if you understand the idea in my answer.

Comment: thanks I experimented with your idea so basically instead of  extracting the files during the docker build I did it beforehand only and it worked.